Why does system data take up so much?
It is taking up 162gb but i am unsure what it is, It also doesnt make sense my apps is only 17 as i have games installed from steam. Thanks I would attach a photo but idk how to sorry. i've tried deleting some stuff like photos and wallpapers. I have a 512 gb storage with 182gb free with only a tiny bit used on apps

i am using macos ventura on a m2 mbp, i have whisky instaleld but not windows or linux

I suggest you look for a "Storage visualizer"/ Disk space analyzer application that shows me exactly how and where the storage space is being used.
I then suggest you take a look at caches, it could be that Messaging Applications such as Telegram automatically download attachments and pictures somewhere, which could take up a lot of space.
In my case I was using an Application called "Mountain duck" for mounting remote file systems on my machine. This application did some sort of smart caching in order to keep files available in case of a disconnect, which ended up taking up about 30 GB in storage. Maybe something similar is happening for you.
